# Model event with relationship data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have an `Expense` model where you can select which currency your expense is. The expense is related to a `Project` model, and the user can set a specific currency for the project as well. For instance, you can have expenses in US Dollars even if you invoice the project in Euros.

So I want to convert the expense to "local currency" (the projects currency) when saving the model.

However, I experienced that when using the `saving` (or even `saved`) event on a model that is not actually saved yet, it will not work getting the currency from the relation.

```php
$project_currency = $model->project->currency;
```

This returns `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'currency' of non-object`

The `ExpenseController` looks like this:

```php
public function store(StoreExpenseRequest $request, Project $project)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $expense = Expense::create( $validated );
    $project->expenses()->save( $expense );
    flash('Expense Saved')->success();
    return redirect()->route('project.show', $project->id);
}
```

Comment: I expect `Expense` has a `project_id` field? Are you setting it? You could fetch the related project before saving the expense and convert it at that moment. Did you try the event `created`?

Comment: Yes, I have a `project_id` field on the `Expense`. I actually havent tried the `creating` event, as I need this event to work on both new and existing models.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. I edited the `store` method on `ExpenseController` to the following:

```php
public function store(StoreExpenseRequest $request, Project $project)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $expense = new Expense( $validated );
    $project->expenses()->save( $expense );
    flash('Expense Saved')->success();
    return redirect()->route('project.show', $project->id);
}
```

And then the `saving` event worked.